# Can preg_match() capture unknown number of occurrences?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Let's say I'm having the following string:

```
$string = 'cats[Garfield,Tom,Azrael]';
```

I need to capture the following strings:

1. `cats`
2. `Garfield`
3. `Tom`
4. `Azrael`

That string can be any word-like text, followed by brackets with the list of comma-separated word-like entries. I tried the following:

```
preg_match('#^(\w+)\[(\w+)(?:,(\w+))*\]$#', $string, $matches);
```

The problem is that `$matches` ignores `Tom`, matching only the first and the last cat.

Now, I know how to do that with more calls, perhaps combining `preg_match()` and `explode()`, so the question is **not** how to do it in general.

The question is: can that be done in single `preg_match()`, so I could validate and match on one go?

Comment: Can you capture string inside square brackets and `split(',',...)` it ?

Comment: Well, actually my use-case is a bit more complex, but the problem stays the same. I would need to do more processing if that couldn't be just single `preg_match()`.

Comment: So if your string was `cats[Garfield,Tom,Azrael] apples`, you would not want _"apples"_ to be selected?

Comment: No - that string would not even pass the `preg_match()`. Validation is one of the reasons I want to keep it on one pattern.

Comment: are you sure preg_match is the best option here?

Comment: Why does it need to be only one statement of `preg_match`? What's stopping you from using other statements, like `explode(',', ...)`?

Comment: @David Because I want to have the format configurable.

Comment: @RoboRobok Can you explain in more detail? Configurable how?

Comment: @David For example, I could change the format from `entity[child1,child2,child3]` to `entity:child1&child2&child3`.

Comment: Look at this, simple and fast. And it won't fail as regexes can because of some unexpected character. https://3v4l.org/EnWIS

Comment: @Andreas - my topic clearly says: `so the question is not how to do it in general.`.

Comment: So it's some kind of school task you got? And your quote here is a bit misleading. You actually wrote: `Now, I know how to do that with more calls, perhaps combining preg_match() and preg_match_all(), so the question is not how to do it in general.` and that is a different thing. I have not combined preg_matches or preg_match_alls. I used string operations and explode.

Comment: No, it's not a school task. It's for my project. I need the flexibility of describing the full pattern by single string.

Comment: I vote close for unclear question now. You have not supplied us with enough information to help you.

Comment: "You", not "us".

Comment: I replaced `preg_match_all()` with `explode()` in the question. The reason I said `preg_match_all()` is because, like I said, my original use-case is more complex. Too complex to ask the question straight away, so I simplified it to just match the problem I have. But in reality, that list inside the brackets is not just `a,b,c`.

Comment: I feel that this is a valid question, but just outside my and possibly your technical knowledge @Andreas

Comment: @David Exactly. And outside my regex knowledge too. But I have a feeling that cannot be done with single regex pattern.

Comment: @David It's not about that. It's about using way to complex functions to do simple tasks. If it was an unpredictable string that could change then a regex would be a good way to solve it. But with a string that has a very fixed pattern regex is not needed. All regex does is make it complex, adds overhead memory use and CPU usage. By some reason people think regex is the answer to all questions here. I do not see it that way. I use regex when I have too, not for the strings with a fixed pattern.

Comment: @Andreas I agree, but it's not the case here. I know this particular example could be done with just strpos-ing, exploding etc. But again - I need validation (very important) and I need configurable string pattern (very important too!). I hope I'm more clear now. So that doesn't need to be regex, but I don't think there is any built-in other option to describe strings as patterns, allowing to get chunks of it through that pattern.

Comment: Again you talk about validation and pattern and stuff but you have not yet given us anything to support those needs. And that means it's a unclear question. Give us those examples you are talking about!

Comment: The need of having flexibility of the string format (which can be, for example, stored in the database - thus being able to CRUD multiple formats) is not enough? I don't need you to design my project - trust me, it's designed fine :)

Comment: Not even speaking of the fact that this question would make sense without any example too. It's very generic question about possibilities of regex. NOT a question how to solve my problem. The title of this topic is quite clear.

Comment: This thread fits nicely: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Believe me or not, but I'm sick of XY problem myself. But this is not the case everywhere! Some questions are about the problem, some questions about the language features. I could easily leave out the example. But your logic of forcing to find another solution and making me explain why I need string pattern is too far. I explained it in details already. This is just a crucial part of this problem - string pattern. I said it 100 times already, and you just keep asking why I need that. That's funny, bro.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying question seems to be: *is it possible to extract each occurrence of a repeated capture group?*

The answer is no.

However, several workarounds exists:

The most understandable uses two steps: you capture the full list and then you split it. Something like:

```
$str = 'cats[Garfield,Tom,Azrael,Supermatou]';
if ( preg_match('~(?<item>\w+)\[(?<list>\w+(?:,\w+)*)]~', $str, $m) )
    $result = [ $m['item'], explode(',', $m['list']) ];
```

*(or any structure you want)*

An other workaround uses `preg_match_all` in conjunction with the `\G` anchor that matches either the start of the string or the position after a successful match:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A),|(?<item>\w+)\[(?=[\w,]+]))(?<elt>\w+)~';
if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches) )
    print_r($matches);
```

This design ensures that all elements are between the brackets.

To obtain a more *flat* result, you can also write it like this:

```
$pattern = '~\G(?!\A)[[,]\K\w+|\w+(?=\[[\w,]+])~';
```

details of this last pattern:

```
~
# first alternative (can't be the first match)
\G (?!\A) # position after the last successful match
          # (the negative lookahead discards the start of the string)
[[,]      # an opening bracket or a comma
\K        # return the whole match from this position
\w+       # an element

|         # OR

# second alternative (the first match)
\w+       # the item
(?=       # lookahead to check forward if the format is correct
    \[        # opening bracket
    [\w,]+    # word characters and comma (feel free to be more descriptive
              # like \w+(?:,\w+)* or anything you want)
    ]         # closing bracket
)
~
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding the question. So, the first workaround is not satisfactory, as we lose the single-pattern idea, needing to explode by comma manually. As for these `\G` ones, is it reliable? Are there any edge cases that would unwillingly pass through, or be rejected, but valid? I'm pretty strict here when it comes to keeping the format. No compromise is acceptable :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple preg_match_all:

```
$string = 'cats[Garfield,Tom,Azrael], entity1[child11,child12,child13], entity2:child21&child22&child23';
preg_match_all('#\w+#', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cats
            [1] => Garfield
            [2] => Tom
            [3] => Azrael
            [4] => entity1
            [5] => child11
            [6] => child12
            [7] => child13
            [8] => entity2
            [9] => child21
            [10] => child22
            [11] => child23
        )

)
```

Comment: Okay - imagine these things in the brackets can be anything, not just a word. So it's `\w+` before the brackets, but anything `[^,]+` inside.

Comment: I'm not sure how ask these kinds of questions. I could tell you my entire problem, but it's too complex, so I simplify it as much as I can. Yet, the answers assume this is the exact thing I wanna do, even though I explained it's not.

Comment: @RoboRobok: Well, edit your question and add real test cases with expected results

Comment: Can you just assume that this is a linguistic question? I just need to know if that can be done with regex - capturing unknown number of occurrences, but not just like "all" `\w+`. My problem doesn't matter here that much, I'm starting to regret I even mentioned it.

Comment: @RoboRobok: I see. I'm afraid that is not possible with a single preg_match if the number of elements inside brakets is unknown.